# Push to github from another machine?

Tags: github

I have created a github account where I have created a repository with a sample project. I have checked out (cloned) this project on a machine A where I have also generated public/private keys using eclipse (Key Management) and uploaded the public key to my github account. I can push my changes on machine A to the github repo just fine.

I have now cloned the repository on another machine B (where I also have generated public/private keys) and added the public key on my github account for machine B. But when I push my changes from machine B to the github repo I get an error, unable to push.

I have seen that "collaborators" can get read/write access to the repo but that requires that I create a new account which seems a bit overkill

How do I push to the github repo from machine B?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To grab a full copy of another user’s repo when you do not have a local repo already, you >will use git clone URL.
>
> For public repos, the URL can be a read-only URL like git://github.com/user/repo.git or an >HTTP read-only URL like http://github.com/user/repo.git.
>   For public repos you own or are a collaborator on, and all private repos, you must use a >private ssh url like git@github.com:user/repo.git.

This is an outtake from help file from github.

EDIT:

Right now, GitHub developed an application for remote sync of repos. You can download it on http://windows.github.com